# How to set a "Date & Time" field for GCP Firestore TTL in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Typescript to insert data into [Google Cloud Platform Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore)
I am able to succesfully insert and access data into Firestore using the provided Google documentation.

However, now I'm trying to set auto-deletion of Firestore entities based on a [TTL field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl). I've specified the name of the TTL field as `myTTL`. So this is how I'm doing it:

```
import { Timestamp } from '@google-cloud/firestore';   // package version 6.6.0
fireBaseEntity.myTTL = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
```

Unfortunately when this is written to Firebase, This entity does not get auto-deleted. I have been told that's because I'm using the wrong datatype. According to the docs, this property should be of type `Date and Time`.

How can I write code to make the datatype of `fireBaseEntity.myTTL` be `Date and Time`? Some sample code would be appreciated. I can't find anything by Googling.

Comment: You haven't said anything about how you created the TTL policy according the to the documentation you linked, nor can we see the code you use to write to Firestore.  Writing code is not enough.  Please edit the question to show your [complete minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all the instructions that anyone can follow to reproduce the issue as you observe it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the Date into a Timestamp, store the myTTL field with an instance of Date and the Firestore library will take care of the rest.

When fetching the document though, it will return that field as an instance of Timestamp.